# Wireshark graph from Payload using Python

Tags: python, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I did not find any solution to this problem yet.

I have a lot of Ethernet-Frames from an Device. In the Payload for example the Voltage measured. I can decode the Value easily with a lua dissector. But then i have to watch every Frame manually.

In Wireshark you can find an I/O Graph, but this only displayes the amount of incoming Frames. Is there any possibility to write an Python Script, that can add an graph with the Voltage Level over all Frames. Or anything else?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the module `scapy` with some graph plotter ?

Comment: I already use scapy, but if you have a pcap with a lot of packets, you can't load them in scapy.